# How to add new var to structure array in Swift 3?

Tags: arrays, swift

Given:

```
var malls: [Mall] = [ 
    Mall(name:"yagey", distance:""), 
    Mall[name:tigey", distance:"") 
]
```

How can I set `distance` to a different String?

```
for mall in malls {
    distance = distanceInMeters
}
```

isn't working.

Thank you!

```
import Foundation


struct Mall {
let name: String
let type: String
let image: String
let time: String
let timeWeek: String
let city: String
let location: String
let adress: String
let cinemaName: String
let productName: String
let numShop: String
let website: String
let schemeWeb: String
let longitude: Double
let latitude: Double
var distance: String
}
```

error:

```
Cannot assign to property: 'mall' is a 'let' constant
```

f

```
func mallToDisplayAt(indexPath: IndexPath) -> Mall {
    var mall: Mall
    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        mall = filteredResultArray[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        mall = malls[indexPath.row]
    }
    return mall
}
```

tableView

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! EateriesTableViewCell
    let mall = mallToDisplayAt(indexPath: indexPath)
    let mallLocate = CLLocation(latitude: mall.latitude, longitude: mall.longitude)
    print (mallLocate)


    let distanceInMeters = mallLocate.distance(from: coords) / 1000

    let distanceInMetersString = String(format: "%.1f", distanceInMeters)

    cell.distanceLabel.text = distanceInMetersString + "км"
    for mall in malls {
    distance = distanceInMeters
   }     return cell
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Mall` is a struct, and then a value type, you need put the updated value back into the array so

```
for index in 0..<malls.count {
    var mall = malls[index] // copy a mall value
    mall.distance = "new value goes here" // change the copy of mall
    malls[index] = mall // put the updated mall back into the array
}
```

Comment: but know i can't sort malls by malls.distance :(

Comment: @dmarinkin: Your question wasn't about sorting. You asked about how to assign a new value to a property of the mall values.

Answer (score 1):

Because struct is value type instead of reference type, modify the copy will not reflect the change to the copy. And by default, `for` loop give you `let` constant which is immutable. So you can't modify it.

You should do this:

```
malls = malls.map { mall in
    var newMall = mall
    newMall.distance = distanceInMeters
    return newMall
}
```

---

The error you are getting is

> Cannot assign to property: 'mall' is a 'let' constant

which means `mall` is a constant variable that you cannot modify. So instead of modify `mall`, you need to copy it and modify copy.

```
var newMall = mall;
newMall.distance = distanceInMeters
```

However you also want to discard the original copy and use the new copy. The easy way is use [`Array.map`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1688519-map) to create a new array with new copies.

Comment: and how can I sort by distance know? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `Mall` defined something like:

```
struct Mall {
    var distance: String
    var name: String

    init...
    ...
    ...
}
```

You have to access the property of the struct

```
for mall in malls {
    mall.distance = distanceInMeters
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply!but it sdoesn't work(

    `struct Mall {
        let name: String
        let distance: String
}`

Comment: Can you add your struct definition to your question.  You might just need to change your `let` to `var`

Comment: @dmarinkin `distance` needs to be declared a variable with `var`, instead of `let` (a constant), if you want to be able to reassign values after initialization

Comment: thank you, guys, but it doesn't work too, maybe because `struct Mall` is in another file Mall.swift?

Comment: That wouldn't be an issue.  Please post your struct definition.  And what does 'doesn't work' mean?  An error?  Value not assigned?  Post all information to your question.

Comment: @frankie I really sorry. posted all information in post

Answer (score 0):

Despite the typos, if you want to create a type `Mall` with only two parameters you need to create a init method in your struct:

```
init(name: String, distance: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.distance = distance
    }
```

Also, as you saw, you cannot edit a value coming from a for loop. What you can do however is something like that:

```
for (index, mall) in malls.enumerated() {
    malls[index].distance = distanceInMeters
}
```

That way instead of modifying the mall you get from the for loop you instead modify the malls array directly.

you could even replace `mall` by `_` as you don't need mall in that example.
Hope it makes sense.